# Which process writes/reads the most from disk over time?

Tags: linux, io

I want to know which process writes/reads the most from disk over time, I mean that I will start the monitoring process than after X time I will be able to see what was the process that used the disk the most.

Is there anything like that?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The answer clearly is "it depends". It will be different for every combination of installed software.

Comment: If you are looking for a monitoring tool to do that, such questions are off topic here. There is a sister site called [softwarerecs.se] where you can ask the question.

Comment: iotop command what you are looking for: https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I don't see how you consider this to be a software recommendation question. The question is asking how to do something with Ubuntu 18.04, so it's already specified which software to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iotop` for this. In batch mode, it can listen for a certain amount of time, printing the processes which used the disks in that time. Try this command:

```
 iotop -toqqqk -n 30|sort -n -r -k 7
```

This will wait for 30 secs, prints the processes doing I/O, and sorts the output so that the most disk-consuming process will be the first. The 7th column is "Disk write", if you want to see the ones doing the most read, sort on the 6th column.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that there is a program called atop for further generations